# k-means clustering on black and white image

Tags: r, image, k-means

### The goal

Let's say we have the following image :

[image]

What I want to do is being able to automatically determine the bounding boxes of each character and crop them into 2 images.

### How that might be done

Croping can be done with the `magick::image_crop` function.

To determine the bounding boxes, I have thought of :

1. converting the image into a matrix of pixels ;

[image: Pixelized image]

2. and applying a k-means clustering in order to identify each character ;
3. determine the coordinates of the outlying pixels for ech charcter, giving me coordinates to apply a croping.

I am stuck at point 1.
I don't know how to convert my image into a useable matrix :

```
library("magick")
path <- "theImage.png"
image_test <- 
  image_read(path) %>%
  image_resize("2000x") %>%
  image_convert(type = 'Grayscale')
```

I [found this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/09/r-k-means-clustering-on-an-image/) but am unsure on how to proceed in my case.

Comment: Are your images going to be as clean as your example?  No speckle?  Well separated regions?

Comment: the solution will be applied to documents such as invoices ; the idea is to detect text areas (symbolized by the characters).